# Difference between ItemTemplateSelector and ListView.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

My goal is to display a list of different items so I picked a `ListView`. But reading [here](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1211/wpf-items-control-advanced-topic) I see that using `ItemControl` and `ItemTemplateSelector` I can pick how I want to display based on the view model. This is what I want. But I also want to display a list of these items. So how do I combine a `ItemControl.ItemTemplateSelector` and a `ListView.ItemTemplate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use `ItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplateSelector` at the same time.

The `ItemTemplateSelector` is supposed to return a DataTemplate for each element in the Items collection, which makes the `ItemTemplate` useless.

See the example in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=net-5.0#examples.